# Delete resources created from template file by Azure az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-deployment, azure-bicep

With `az deployment group create --template-file vm.bicep -g "Something"`, I can create just fine things which are defined in the file `vm.bicep` (or ARM template `vm.json` for that matter).

But how do I actually get rid of EXACTLY just the resources that had been created by running create with a template file? `az deployment group delete` doesn't support a `--template-file` parameter.

Edit: Clarification: I only want to get rid of what has been created by the template. Not everything in a Resource Group.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I would use some kind of tagging in this case, and later delete all with the corresponding tag